# Read from Blob using Php/Ajax Oracle

Tags: php, ajax, oracle, pdf, blob

I am a newbie to PHP development. I want to fetch pdf documents stored in a blob column and display them in `href` on different pages of my website. But the problem is it shows adobe reader error that says:

"The PDF Document cannot be displayed correctly"

So far (for the sake of simplicity) I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<a href = "readMe.php?id=21">Click here!</a>

</body> 
</head>
</html>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$id = $_GET[id];
$conn = OCILogon("abc","abc","abcserver");

$qry = "select blob_file,doc_name from doc_data where ID =".$id;

$stmt = ociparse ($conn,$qry);

OCIDefineByName($stmt,"BLOB_FILE",$blobFile);
OCIDefineByName($stmt,"DOC_NAME",$blobFileName);
OCIExecute($stmt);

while ($rowResult = OCIFetch($stmt))
{
if($rowResult != null){

$a = $rowResult[0];

}
}
header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
header('Content-disposition: inline;filename='.$blobFileName.'.pdf'); 
echo $a;

?>
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it makes sense, but I replaced the code from:

```
while ($rowResult = OCIFetch($stmt))
{
if($rowResult != null){
$a = $rowResult[0];
}
```

to this:

```
while ( $row = OCI_Fetch_Array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS) ) 
{
$a = $row['BLOB_FILE'];
}
```

Keeping the rest of the code same and now it displays all pdf's in the browser beautifully. Chow :)